# databinding expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have an VS2005 ASP.Net page with a repeater on it of Customers.

The following shows up in the  of the repeater:

```
<span><%# Eval(GetAdLinks((Customer)Container.DataItem)) %></span>
```

The GetAdLinks is a protected method in the code behind which returns a control represented as a string. Is this possible?

I'm getting an error that says Customer does not contain a property with the name ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post the signature for the GetAdLinks method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a client-side (no runat="server") control, then it should be possible. But you should not include it in an Eval(). I'm guessing it should look somewhat like this:

```
<%# GetAdLinks(Container.DataItem) %>
```

The GetAdLinks method should be refactored to accept the Container.DataItem as a DataRowView object. Inside the method, you can cast it to a Customer object, which you can figure out with a little debugging.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The better wayu to do this would be to add a `Literal` to your `Repeater` template and then implement the OnDataBinding method.  This is exactly what a `Literal` is for.

Here is an example:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litYourControl" runat="server" OnDataBinding="litYourControl_DataBinding" />
```

Then in your codebehind implement it:

```
protected void litYourControl(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lt = (Literal)(sender);
    // Not sure what field you are binding to based on the example in your question
    // so I will just make an assumption.
    Customer cus = (Customer)(Eval("Container.DataItem"));
    lt.Text = GetAdLinks(cus);
}
```